# async fetch triggered three times

Tags: reactjs

I use this in my react app to fetch data from my backend server:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWidgets = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1202/data");
      const responseData = await response.json();
      setData(responseData);
      console.log(responseData);
    };
    fetchWidgets();
  });
```

It fetching data works fine, but the function seems to be triggered three times for some reason. 
`responseData` is logged three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.useEffect` runs every time after component renders, unless you tell it not by defining a `dependency array` as its second argument; since you are setting a state inside its body which causes the comonent to re-render, you will see it happens multiple times. to fix the problem you may pass an empty array `[]` it will only run once after first render and acts like `componentDidMount` in class components. or add some dependency to run only if the dependencies change;

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWidgets = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1202/data");
      const responseData = await response.json();
      setData(responseData);
      console.log(responseData);
    };
    fetchWidgets();
},[]);
```

Comment: I took the code from a tutorial and deleted it because I thought it was unnecessary... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Empty Brackets for the second parameter of useEffect.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWidgets = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1202/data");
      const responseData = await response.json();
      setData(responseData);
      console.log(responseData);
    };
    fetchWidgets();
  },[]);
```

That will ensure the useEffect only runs once.

Comment: Thank you for your help.